# Switching from Twitter Bootstrap to TODC Bootstrap: What's involved?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently on our website, we are using Twitter Bootstrap just the way it came. It's a nice theme and allowed us to make a site that looked decently professional very quickly, but the three of us working on the website agree that we'd prefer a Google-styled theme, like the kind used in Google Inbox or their new tool Google Classroom.

Initially, I didn't want to switch because of the amount of work that would be involved in going from Bootstrap to Google's Material Design. After a little searching I found a website called TODC Bootstrap which looks promising - it's Bootstrap, but with a Google theme.

I was wondering if anyone knew how I would go about switching from one to the other and what's involved. Is it as easy as swapping some CSS stylesheets, or are some of the classnames and such different so I have to modify my HTML a bit?